# Calculate Orthogonality of 2 Identical Curves

Tags: analysis, functions, orthogonality

I have the following question

I have two identical functions:

f(x)= -cosh(x)
g(x)= f(x)

How much do I have to move g(x) along the x-axis, so that f(x) and g(x) create a 90° angle between the two curves and the intersection P.

Thanks in advance